# pg_dump 0 bytes backup file, stuck after saving database definition

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to backup Postgres database but I always get 0 bytes backup size. If I use the verbose switch, I can see that it is stuck at

```
pg_dump: saving database definition
```

I have tried taking backup of specific table and it works fine. Below is my command:

```
pg_dump -U backupuser -p 5432 -Ft -v -d database > database.tar
```

Comment: Start a second client connection and look at `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks` to see what blocks the backup.

Comment: I am running into the same problem. The dump _does not_ get stuck when exporting data only via the `-a` flag. It _does_ get stuck when a schema export is involved.

Also, in my case the source database is an AWS RDS instance. I tried @LaurenzAlbe's suggestion but couldn't make much sense of the 200+ locks: there was one `virtualxid` `ExclusiveLock` and the rest where `AccessShareLock`s on tables.

Comment: @ThomasJung Look for locks with `granted = FALSE`. Start your own question, add all the information there and ideally link to this question (so it can be closed as a duplicate).

Comment: I'm dumping out a backup, and it was stuck on 68K for a good 15 minutes before the file started growing again.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this. When I was creating the backup, I checked the postgres logs and it was clearly written there that during backup the server wasn't reachable. Now to resolve this, I have added a command to restart the postgres before the scheduled backup and it is working fine now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).